# Number of Bases in $C^8$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vectors

Consider the set of all the vectors in $C^8$ each of whose coordinates is either 0 or 1.

How many different bases does this set contain?

Comment: By C^8, do you mean $\Bbb C^8$, the $8$-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers?

Comment: no closed form is known for this, see here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18636/number-of-invertible-0-1-real-matrices

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo What does your comment mean? The answer will be a number.

Comment: @IgorRivin I mean that no formula has been found for a general $n$, of course it is easy to solve with brute force, the link I gave contains the link to the OEIS sequence, the answer for $n=8$ is $8286284310367538176$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: No, that is the number of matrices that are _not_ invertible. You need to subtract that from $2^{64}$.

Comment: in hindsight brute force may not be the way to go for this one, but surely some combination of computers and intelligent casework.

Comment: @HenningMakholm oh yeah, of course. Sorry about that.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I am sure the numbers have not been obtained by brute force, since iterating through $2^{64}$ possibilities might take a while. The obvious hack of looking at the vectors in sorted order saves a factor of $8!$ gets you down to $2^{49},$ which is still largish.

Comment: @IgorRivin maybe you can get it down by stopping if the first $k$ rows are allready LD. Although there's probably more stuff involved, I don't know really xD.

Comment: I saw that you already had a comment in the link I posted.